# Xubuntu Backlit Keyboard not working on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, samsung, keyboard-backlight

Xubuntu 14.04 Backlit Keyboard not working on Samsung Series 7 NP730U3E with Voria PPA and Samsung-tools installed. Works fine with Ubuntu/Kubuntu 14.04 but prefer XFCE though gather XFCE is likely the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation in the version of xfce4-power-manager in Xubuntu 14.04.  It was recently fixed upstream (starting with 1.3.0), with updated packages in Xubuntu 14.10 resolving this issue.

xfce4-power-manager is in active development, recent release announcements below.

1.3.0: https://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce-announce/2014-June/000326.html

1.3.1: https://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce-announce/2014-August/000330.html

1.3.2: https://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce-announce/2014-August/000332.html